# Where to establish connection to sql in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have never used Visual Studio 2017 (or previous versions) before and have been asked to work on a project that includes getting information from a sql database. I am trying to open a connection to the database using an external config and then using configSource in my App config. However when I run this code I get an error: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. I have been doing a bit of research on this but I'm uncertain of some of VS features and syntax. First, does the ConnectionString need to be initialized in the app config or somewhere else like a module or form? Here are my app config and external config code. 
External config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsApp4.My.MySettings.TrakConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=Trak;Initial Catalog=Trak;User 
        ID=TrakMe;Password = TrakMeData;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

App config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
     <connectionStrings configSource ="external_conn.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Connection String is normally independent on Visual Studio. It is used when your app is connection to Database which use for their work. If you need to connect to database from Visual Studio and manage this database you can connect to database via `Server Explorer` window. If you do not see that you ken show it in `View` menu or typing "Server Explorer" to search box in right top header of window at left of minimize button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer your question**

- I have always kept my connection strings in the app.config file. I can't think of a good reason to keep it in a separate file, so I would suggest moving it to app.config.
- The `Data Source` should be the address of the server hosting the SQL database. If this is your machine you should use `localhost`, if it is a dedicated server you could use the server's IP address.
- I don't think it could be the spaces around the equal sign for `Password` but I would get rid of those if only for consistency. Voodoo might be making your password " TrakMeData"

**What I would do**

Just let VS handle it by using Entity Framework to make the database connection. Right click in your Solution Explorer and select `Add` > `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, enter a name and select `EF Designer from database`. Create a "New Connection..." and you'll have a handy dandy interface with a "Test Connection" button so you don't have to keep recompiling to see if the connection string in your app.config is correct. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878)'s a tutorial (that follows a different path to the same result) with pictures! You can probably skip the database creation bit as I'm assuming you already have one up somewhere.